# Realm define custom query conditions

Tags: android, realm

I want to achieve something similar to this.
Suppose I have a realm object `Food`.

```
class Food extends RealmObject {
    // stuff
}
```

And a functional interface like this one

```
interface IsHealthy {
    boolean isHealthy (Food food);
}
```

The `IsHealthy` interface provides a way to determine if a `Food` is healthy or not by doing some computations on the `Food` object.

Is there a way to write a realm query that uses this condition in order to get only the `Healthy Foods` from the realm database? I have been unable to achieve this, and for now I'm doing a workaround by getting all the Foods and checking them one by one once the `RealmQueryResult` is in the memory, but this is somehow a hack, and doesn't perform well.

Comment: `by doing some computations on the Food object` define computations

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This depends on the implementation of the interface. The idea id to have many implementations of that interface and use the it as a filter when querying the realm database. The realm object is immutable btw.

Comment: There is no such thing as an immutable RealmObject.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce What I mean is that I'm not mutating the realmObject when doing the isHealthy computation.

Comment: This question still depends entirely on what an implementation looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Realm doesn't support such custom conditions. You are limited to do single checks per attribute and combine those checks to filter your realm objects.

You can create an interface that looks like this

```
interface IsHealthy {
    RealmQuery isHealthy (RealmQuery<Food> query);
}
```

One implemntation of this interface could look like this

```
class ForKids implements IsHealthy {
    @Override
    RealmQuery isHealthy (RealmQuery<Food> query){
        return query.lessThan("sugar",10 /*or whatever*/)
                    .isNotNull("vitamine");
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this

```
ForKids forKids = new ForKids();
forKids.isHealthy(realm.where(Food.class)).findAll();
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Wow! This answer is so cleaver sir! Thank you!!

Comment: Hope it helped you.